# changing HTML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I change this html:

```
<div data-label="FileInput">
    <img src="the source"></img>
    <div>Stuff</div>
    ... etc ...
</div>
```

To a file input using jQuery? I cannot change the structure of the html, and I need to target the container div (data-label="FileInput")..

I'm still a beginner with js / jQuery, so if you could be explicit with how to do this I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: div[data-label='FileInput']

Comment: What do you mean change the html "To a file input"? Let the user input the file path/select a file on their system?

Comment: @Andrew yes exactly. Thanks for any ideas. Added to the question to make it more clear..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
$("div[data-label=FileInput]").replaceWith("<input type='file' />");
```